# Java Variables Shadowed Methods overridden concept

Tags: java, variables, inheritance, overriding, shadowing

I am struggling to understand Variables Shadowed Methods Overriden Concept of inheritance with Java.

Case 1:

```
class Car{
   public int gearRatio = 8;
   public String accelerate() {  return "Accelerate : Car";  }
}
class SportsCar extends Car{
   public int gearRatio = 9;
   public String accelerate() {  return  "Accelerate : SportsCar";  }
   public static void main(String[] args){
      Car c = new SportsCar();
      System.out.println( c.gearRatio+"  "+c.accelerate() );
   }
}
```

Output: 8 Accelerate : Sportscar.

Case 2:

```
public class TestClass{
   public static void main(String args[ ] ){
      A o1 = new C( );
      B o2 = (B) o1;
      System.out.println(o1.m1( ) );
      System.out.println(o2.i );
   }
}
class A { int i = 10;  int m1( ) { return i; } }
class B extends A { int i = 20;  int m1() { return i; } }
class C extends B { int i = 30;  int m1() { return i; } }
```

Output: 30, 20

So if I understand correctly, the super class variable is always called unless the sub classes variable is called explicitly. But the opposite is true for methods where the sub classes overridden method is called unless the super class is called explicitly.

I would think variables and methods should work the same or there should be a compile error when creating sub classes with the same variables.

Can someone explain if this is correct and why java works like this please.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> I would think variables and methods should work the same or there should be a compile error when creating sub classes with the same variables.

Well, that's simply not the way Java works.

Variables are *not* handled polymorphically - there's no concept of "overriding" a variable. Methods, however, *are* handled polymorphically. *Behaviour* can be specialized, but not *state*.

Note that if your variables are private, as they almost always should be, the situation is never even visible.

Comment: +1 for "Note that if your variables are private, as they almost always should be, the situation is never even visible"

Comment: So the concept of why variables are not handled polymorphically is not important because they should always be handled through methods which are polymorphic?

Answer (score 1):

In java there is no `Instance variable overriding concept` and variables are not polymorphic as methds.

So in your case, if you use :

```
Car c = new SportsCar();  // c is Object reference of type Car
System.out.println( c.gearRatio+"  "+c.accelerate() );
```

`c.gearRatio` refers to the gearRatio in `Car` and `not from SportsCar`. In case of method `c.accelerate()`, method is overridden in `SportsCar` and it is `SportsCar` object, so `SportsCar.accelerate()` is called.

```
public static void main(String args[ ] ){
  A o1 = new C( );  // object reference is of type A and object is C
  B o2 = (B) o1;   // object of C can be type casted to B as B is parent to C
  System.out.println(o1.m1( ) ); // C.m1() will be called.  
  System.out.println(o2.i );   // o2 is type B, so B.i will be printed
}
```