# Wrong output with printf()

Tags: java, inheritance, printf

Why am I keeping getting 0.0000 in the output ? I've put here some code which is main class, one of the child classes FragGrenade and parent class -Explosive. I keep getting 0.0000 from the method public void explode() and I guess I'm doing smth wrong with printf(). Could someone help me with that?

```
public class ExplosiveDemo{

    public static void main(String args[]){

        Explosive frag = new FragGrenade(15.5);

        System.out.println( frag.isRadioactive() ); 
        // false
        frag.explode();
        System.out.println();
        // OUTPUT:
        // Boom: blast radius 15.50 meters

        Explosive nuke = new Nuke(3.2);
        System.out.println(nuke.isRadioactive() ); 
        // true
        nuke.explode();
        // OUTPUT:
        // Boom: blast radius 3200.00 meters
        // Area irradiated
  }
public class FragGrenade extends Explosive{

    protected double blastRadiusMeters;

    public FragGrenade(double blastRadiusMeters)
    {
        super(blastRadiusMeters);
    }

    public void explode()
    {
        System.out.printf("Boom: blast radius %f meters\n", this.blastRadiusMeters);
    }
    public boolean isRadioactive()
    {
        return false;
    }


}

}


public abstract class Explosive {

    protected double blastRadiusMeters;

    public Explosive(double blastRadiusMeters)
    {
        this.blastRadiusMeters = blastRadiusMeters;
    }

    public void explode()
    {
        System.out.printf("Boom: blast radius %.2 meters\n", this.blastRadiusMeters);
    }
    public boolean isRadioactive()
    {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: %.2 - did you mean %f ?

Comment: But does'n the child method overrides the parent's method? @BarrySW19. And that would still give me 0.000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In derived class you declared another

```
protected double blastRadiusMeters;
```

but in constructor via

```
public FragGrenade(double blastRadiusMeters) {
    super(blastRadiusMeters);//here
}
```

you are setting value of this field from super class `Explosive`.

You should probably change your classes to

```
public class FragGrenade extends Explosive {

    public FragGrenade(double blastRadiusMeters) {
        super(blastRadiusMeters);
    }

}
```

and simply use inherited versions of methods from `Explosive` class.

To make it work you will also need to correct `%.2` in your `printf`. It should be `%.2f`.

Comment: Thank you, @Pshemo! One last question: why do I get an error in another child-class in this line:System.out.printf("Boom: blast radius %f kilometers\n", this.blastAreaKilometers * 1000);.... But when I change to blastRadiusMeters then it gives me result?

Comment: @Nikola What error you are getting? Judging by your example I suspect that this may be related with tack that you are trying to multiply `this.blastAreaKilometers` (which you probably don't have) by 1000, instead of `this.blastRadiusMeters`.

Comment: thank you again, I'm struggling about how the protected variable of the parent class can be accesses in a child class

Comment: @Nikola Then make your variable `private` in parent class so it will be accessible only by this class. You can add `public` or `protected` method `double getBlastRadiusMeters(){return blastRadiusMeters;}` inside it, so derived class would be able to get value from inside its super class, but wouldn't be able to change it.

Answer (score 0):

You define the exact same variable `protected double blastRadiusMeters;` in both the subclass and superclass. When this happens, the subclass shadows the superclass, which means that accessing `this.blastRadiusMeters` will access the one in FragGrenade, which has never been set.

Try removing everything from your subclass except for the constructor

```
public class FragGrenade extends Explosive{

    public FragGrenade(double blastRadiusMeters)
    {
        super(blastRadiusMeters);
    }
}
```

Comment: Here's some more info to help you understand: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12086298/why-instance-variable-of-super-class-is-not-overridden-in-sub-class-method

Comment: You're right @Zach Sadler. But I also have another subclass which has different variable into the constructor, i've described that below.

Comment: @Nikola The reason that Nuke works is because you used a different variable name - `blastAreaKilometers` instead of `blastRadiusMeters`

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Nuke extends Explosive {

    protected double blastAreaKilometers;

    public Nuke(double blastAreaKilometers)
    {
        super(blastAreaKilometers);
    }

    public void explode()
    {
        System.out.printf("Boom: blast radius %f kilometers\n", this.blastAreaKilometers * 1000);
    }
    public boolean isRadioactive()
    {
        return true;
    }

}
```