# Accessing private instances in child class

Tags: java, inheritance

I've seen answers for questions related to mine on Stack Overflow, but I am still left with some ambiguity.  A parent class method has access to its own private instance variables.  If a child class inherits the class, what happens when the `getA()` method is called on an instance of the `Child` class?  Does it return the `a` from the `Parent` class or the `a` from the `Child` class?

```
class Parent {
    private int a = 10;  
    public int getA() {
       return a;
    }
 }

class Child extends Parent {
    private int a = 22;              
 }

public class Test { 
   public static void main(String []args) throws Exception {        
       Child c = new Child(); 
       System.out.println(c.getA());
   }    
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the Method `getA()` is inherited, if you call this Method, you'll always invoke the `Parent`'s Method.

The current Object will be treated as a `Parent` and not as a `Child`, and the `Parent`'s a will be returned.

Even though you have your own variable `a`, this variable wont override the `Parent`'s `a`. They are different from each other, have different addresses and different values.

If you want `getA()` to return `Child`'s `a`, you need to override the Method to return your new variable.

```
class Child extends Parent {
    private int a = 22;

    @Override
    public int getA(){
        return a;
    }
 }
```

You could also "go crazy" and do stuff like the following:

```
class Child extends Parent {
    private int a = 22;       

    @Override
    public int getA(){
        int superA = super.getA();

        return a+superA;    
    }
 }
```

That way you could return the sum of `Parent`'s and `Child`'s `a`.

(Just an example)

Answer (score 2):

This is a duplicate of [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12086298/why-instance-variable-of-super-class-is-not-overridden-in-sub-class-method).

The variable `a` in subclass `Child` hides the `a` in the parent class `Parent`.

Comment: I know that it hides, that's not what I want actually

Comment: @KishoreKumarKorada then what do you want?

Comment: I know that fields can't be inherited but methods does. So when I have getA() in child class doesn't it pick child's a instance variable?

Comment: @KishoreKumarKorada note that whether private fields are inherited depends on how you define "inherited", and there isn't an official definition. In some ways they are, in some ways they aren't. (I removed the part from my answer that said they weren't)

Answer (score 1):

Fields cannot be overridden.

In your code, an instance of child (like the one referred to by `c`) has *two different fields, which are both called `a`*.

You cannot access `Parent`'s private variables inside `Child`, full stop. That's the entire point of `private`. There is nothing* you can write inside `Child` to make the parent's `a` field equal 22.

* Technically, you could with reflection. Reflection doesn't count though, since its purpose is essentially to allow you to break things, and do things that are otherwise impossible.

Comment: As I understood the question, it's not about changing `Parent`'s `a` to be 22, but why `getA()` will always return the `Parent`'s `a`, even though he has his own new `a` variable

Comment: The take-home message to remember here is that methods **can** be overridden by their subclasses, but variables **cannot** be overridden.

Comment: @Loki The original question was mistaken on that point, I believe.

Comment: @Loki Yes, That's what exactly I want to know

Answer (score 1):

Private variables are local to the class and in your code you are inheriting the properties of the parent class so you can access getA() and it will return the parent's attribute.
And you cannot access child's variable unless you have public getter method for child attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Stick to basics "private member variable will only be accessed within the class by its own member functions and fields cannot be inherited" so basically when you are accessing the private variable A in parent class , the method is supposed to access its own private member rather then the private field of any child class.