# Why the overridden method not exhibting polymorphic behaviour?

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

I know [Variables doesn't exhibit polymorphic behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12086298/why-instance-variable-of-super-class-is-not-overridden-in-sub-class-method) and its limited to methods. But below code is bit confusing in returning the type of object.

Its invoking the child method (which is right) and that means it is returning the child object. So why not printing the child variable's value?

```
class Parent {

    int var = 11;

    public Parent getInstance() {
        System.out.println("In Parent ...");
        return new Parent();
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {

    int var = 22;

    public Child getInstance() {
        System.out.println("In Child ...");
        return new Child();
    }
}


public class VariableHiding {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Parent p = new Child();
        System.out.println(p.getInstance().var);  // something's fishy?
    }
}


// Output : In Child ...  11
```

PS : Its not the duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12086298/why-instance-variable-of-super-class-is-not-overridden-in-sub-class-method) (which talks about variable not taking part in polymorphism, but the one mentioned here returns the object of child obj and that obj holds var of parent instead of its own)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return type of `p.getInstance()` is `Parent`, since `p`'s compile-time type is `Parent`, and the `getInstance()` method of `Parent` returns a `Parent`.

You can see that if you try to write:

```
Parent p = new Child();
Child c = p.getInstance();
```

which won't pass compilation.

Therefore `p.getInstance().var` returns the instance variable of `Parent` class.

In order to get the instance variable of `Child` class, you'll have to cast `p.getInstance()` to `Child`:

```
System.out.println(((Child)p.getInstance()).var);
```

or change the type of `p` to `Child`:

```
Child p = new Child();
System.out.println(p.getInstance().var);
```

Comment: But The p.getInstance() evaluates to CHILD object, right?

Comment: @Snehal the runtime type is Child, not the compile time type.

Answer (score 1):

**Runtime polymorphism** cannot be achieved for variables. So both the `class Parent and Child` have a common variable `var`.

```
Parent p = new Child();
```

In this `p`, referred by `class Child`(which is of type of class Parent).So it will always refer to super class variable.

Answer (score 0):

The output is 11 instead of 22 because with line

```
 Parent p=new Child();
```

has been declared a reference to Parent, not to Child. This is legal ( Child is a Parent ) but from the point of view of the variable **var** the object even if costructed as a Child is considered a Parent, so the value written in Child is not considered.
The story would be completely different if the variable var was defined within the costructors, in the following way

```
 class Parent {

    protected int var;

    Parent(){ var=11;}

    public Parent getInstance() {
        System.out.println("In Parent ...");
        return new Parent();
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {

    Child(){ var=22;}

    public Child getInstance() {
        System.out.println("In Child ...");
        return new Child();
    }
}
```

This time using the same main function the result is 22,as desidered, because the value 11 defined in Parent's costuctor is overriden by the value 22 defined in the Child's one.