# Extend a class and redefine a final variable

Tags: java, android

In my app I have two classes:

```
public class A  
{
    public final int value;
 
    A(int value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    } 
}
 
public class Mutable_A  
{
    public int value;
 
    A(int valule)
    {
        super(a);
        this.value = value;
    } 
}
```

and in the code I do this:

```
 A a = new Mutable_A(50);
 ...
 ((Mutable_A) a).value = 60;
 ...
 if (A.value == 60)
 {
     print "I'm 60";
 } else {     
     print "I'm 50";    
 }
```

Theorically `a.value` is `60`, but due to I declare `a` as a `A` variable (instead of a `Mutable_A` variable), the value of `a.value` is `50`.

Is there a way to correct this?

Comment: I assume you meant MutableA to **extend** Mutable? Please always provide true [mcve], not some pseudo code you consider meaningful.

Comment: Beyond that see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12086298/why-is-an-instance-variable-of-the-superclass-not-overridden-by-a-subclass ...

Comment: The only answer is: there is no real inheritance for fields. Simply: dont do it.

Comment: It is not possible to use another class as a constructor.   Do you mean it extends class A. If it does then instance variables are not overridden. So this should not be a problem.
Share a running code if possible.

Comment: Not only is there no inheritance for fields, but there is no overriding for 'final'.  So that's two reasons for "don't do it",

Comment: Mutable_A extends A. The difference BTW A and Mutable_A is only one: A defines a final variable and Mutable_A defines the same variable but not final.

Answer (score 0):

When you create an object of `Mutable_A`, it stores two variables called `value`.

Initially you set both variables to 50. Then you change the one declared in Mutable_A class to 60.

End result: One variable is set to 50 and the other is set to 60. This is the expected behavior.

It sounds like you want to use only the variable declared in Mutable_A. You can achieve that by adding a `get` method that can be overridden:

```
public class A  
{
    private final int value;
 
    A(int value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    } 
    int getValue() { return this.value; }
}
 

public class Mutable_A  
{
    private int value;
 
    A(int valule)
    {
        super(a);
        this.value = value;
    } 

    void setValue(int value) { this.value = value; }
    int getValue() { return this.value; }
}
```

Now, a.getValue() will return the updated value, because you end up calling the overridden method:

```
((Mutable_A) a).setValue(60);
if (a.getValue() == 60) {
    // will enter here
```

That said, this isn't great design, because you have two copies of the variable with the same name and it may not be easy to know which one gets used where.